# T38modem manuals?

Tags: sip, fax, modem

Are there any T38modem users here?

I'm trying to figure out how to call T38modem with SIP. I've got everything except the --route option for receiving. I know my own phone number, but I am not sure how to set it up.

Currently, I have:

```
--route "modem:0.*"="sip:<dn>@64.136.174.30" --route "modem:1.*=sip:18778469183@127.0.0.1"
```

I've also tried:

```
--route "modem:*.*"="sip:<dn>@64.136.174.30" --route"sip:*@74.94.184.154"="modem:<dn>@127.0.0.1"
```

what amI doing wrong? And where (other than t38modem --help) can I find some documentation on how to use it?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might help(as a start) --> http://sourceforge.net/projects/t38modem/files/. While it is not exactly what you are looking for it has some documentation that might port to your problem.

Comment: I've already got the program compiled and running, so I already HAVE all of the tarball. but the documentation in there is basically a man page, which is not sufficiently detailed...